# Write data to output file

Tags: export

since I am new to Wolfram Mathematica I am wondering if somebody can help me with my problem. (it is simple I guess)

Basically I would like to extract the data from a function I defined in Mathematica an write this data to a output file (for instance a .dat file)

Here's my function:

`w[x_]=0.00142878 Sin[3.14159 x]`

Now I would like to fill the first column of the output-file with the data of `w`.
Therefore I did the following loop and to show you the results I displayed the output.

`For[x = 0.0, x <= 1, x += 0.2, PutAppend[w[x], "w.dat"]]`

```
FilePrint["w.dat"]
0.
0.0008398150100260654
0.0013588492304845074
0.0013588492304845074
0.0008398150100260655
1.7497491811730056*^-19
```

My question is how it is possible to modify the output of `w` that:

1. all the results have the same number of digits and
2. to rewrite the result to `...E-19` instead of `...*^-19`.

***Thank you guys in advance!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Control the number of digits

```
format[number_, digits_ : 4] :=
 StringReplace[
  TextString[
   EngineeringForm[number, digits, ExponentFunction -> (If[-10 < # < 10, Null, #] &)]],
  {".*10^" -> "E", "*10^" -> "E"}]

Table[format[w[x]], {x, 0, 1, .2}]
(* {"0.", "0.0008398", "0.001359", "0.001359", "0.0008398", "1.75E-19"} *)

Table[format[w[x], 3], {x, 0, 1, .2}]
(* {"0.", "0.00084", "0.00136", "0.00136", "0.00084", "1.75E-19"} *)
```

---

Here is one way to do it

```
data = Table[StringReplace[ToString@FortranForm@w[x], "e" -> "E"], {x, 0, 1, .2}]
Export["data.dat", data, "Text"]
```

You might also want to replace `3.14159` with `Pi`.

Comment: Thank you Rohit, that worked very well. The only thing I would also like to know, is how I can adjust the number of digits? Can you also help me with that?

Comment: It would be nice if somebody can help me to modify the data of `w` so that I just export this data set with eg. four digits of each value?

Comment: Try using [NumberForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm.html) for more control over the number of digits.

Comment: @WM_noob5 Added a way to control number of digits. Not sure if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: @RohitThat was my bad. I am embarrassed to say that I've only just seen your comment on the control of the digits by now. First I just saw the things you wrote beneath "Here is one way to do it"... **Thank you so much, you really helped me a lot**